# Weird NullpointerException android.content.ComponentName

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this line of code, I am getting a NullPointerException here

Line 219 Search.java

> > Intent intent = new Intent((Context) actionBar, SearchResultsMap.class)

Exception

```
04-25 17:30:00.485: W/System.err(6518): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 17:30:00.501: W/System.err(6518):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
04-25 17:30:00.501: W/System.err(6518):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2823)
04-25 17:30:00.501: W/System.err(6518):     at com.itaxeeta.server.Search.onPostExecute(Search.java:219)
```

AndroidManifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.itaxeeta.SearchResultsMap"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
```

Seems like SearchResultsMap.class is coming up as Null, but how could it, its a Activity and its right there. It happens randomly, often. What am I missing ?

Edit : Added some more code for clarity.

Inside Activity

```
public class HomeScreen extends MapActivity implements IActionBar
   ....
   onClick() {
   ....
   new Search(this, source, destination).execute();    
   ...
   }
}
```

Search class

```
 public Search(IActionBar actionBar, GeoPoint source, GeoPoint destination) {
    super(actionBar);
    this.source = source;
    this.destination = destination;
}

public interface IActionBar {
    public void setBusyVisibility(int visibility) ;
    public void setSubscribedToCount() ;
    public void setCurrentAddress(String address) ;
    public void setSubscribedToDetails(CustomJourneyUserInformation[] result);
    public Context getContext() ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchResultsMap.class)
```

OR

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Your_ClassName.this, SearchResultsMap.class)
```

Instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent((Context) actionBar, SearchResultsMap.class)
```

Comment: Added more code for clarity. Sorry, should have added it before.

Comment: Your_ClassName.this gives `No enclosing instance of the type HomeScreen is accessible in scope`

Comment: then give Your_ClassName.class

Comment: I then get `The constructor Intent(Class<HomeScreen>, Class<SearchResultsMap>) is undefined`

Comment: Did you extends Activity class in your Search class

Comment: I think that without extend it you can't use Intent.. I wont conclude this statement i think so..

Comment: Did not understand. Sorry.

Comment: I post another answer also try that

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBar` cannot be cast to `Context`, more than that, seems it's `null` at the time you instantiate the `Intent`. If this code is executed inside an `Activity`, just pass `this` as the first parameter.

Comment: Thats what I did, In HomeScreen I implemented IActionBar (which has getContext()) and then I called `new Search(this, source, destination).execute();`. In Search (async task) I pass actionBar. Should have worked. Infact it does, rarely I get a exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Intent in AsyncTask then use this code,

```
public class Search extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Main> {  
      @Override
        protected Main doInBackground(Main... params) { 
             return params[0]; 
       }
     protected void onPostExecute(Main params) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent intent = new Intent(params,SearchResultsMap.class); 
         startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception.
In my case, it is because when I run below code:
 the Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class)
The activity already finished. then it is null.

Hope help others.